# Should I ceil or floor when finding lower bound of height of binary tree?

Tags: algorithms, trees, binary

It seems that I have confusion and/or wrong understanding. I'm trying to understand the lower bound on height. For a tree with a given height H, the maximum number of nodes on all levels is $n \le 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2+...+2^H = 2^{H+1}-1$.
Therefore we get:
$$
 \\
log(n+1) \le H+1 \\
H \ge \lfloor log(n+1) \rfloor -1
$$
My understanding is that it means that a tree with $n$ nodes can be minimum of height $ \lfloor log(n+1) \rfloor -1$.

But, it doesn't seem to be correct. If, for examplle, $n=4$ we get $ H=\lfloor log(4+1) \rfloor -1=1$.

It's clearly wrong, since the height is 2

[image]

1. I noticed that if I ceil instead of floor then I get the correct value.
2. In other places I saw people mentioning $H \ge log(n)-1$ instead of $H \ge log(n+1)-1$

Comment: You should have a ceil.  You have $H \ge \log(n + 1) - 1$.  Note that $H$ cannot equal $\lfloor \log(n + 1) \rfloor - 1$ because this is less than $\log(n + 1) - 1$.

Comment: First, $H\ge \log(n+1)-1$. And then since $H$ is an integer, the possible range of $H$ is further restricted by $H\ge \lceil \log(n+1)\rceil-1\ge \log(n+1)-1$.

Comment: @peterwhy, can you explain why I should have ceil since $H$ is an integer?

Comment: @theateist If, for examplle, $n=4$ we get $H \ge \log(4+1)-1 = 1.32\ldots$ which is not an integer. If $H$ is an integer, then the possible $H$ from this inequality may only be $2,3,\ldots$, i.e. $H\ge \lceil \log(4+1)\rceil - 1$.

Comment: @peterwhy, I do understand that since I know that $H$ should be 2 I want to use ceil. What I meant is, assuming I don't know the answer, why/how would I know that I need ceil and not floor? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: @theateist The other choice using floor would sometimes include wrong $H$ that is less than $\log(n+1)-1$, as Joseph Camacho mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @peterwhy So, it was decided to use ceil and not floor purely by observation? I thought there was a more mathematical explanation.